# Webpack warning when starting plutus-playground-client

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, plutus-pab

I am getting a warning when I run npm start on the plutus-playground-client:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/datapool/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/dist
⚠ ｢wdm｣: WARNING in Compiling Unsafe.Coerce
```

And at the end I get flagged the final output:

```
webpack compiled with 1 warning
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

The problem seems to stem from Unsafe.Coerce. Any explanation on this and how I might avoid the warning?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to be concerned about. I see it reporting a different module for the warning.

```
⚠ ｢wdm｣: WARNING in Compiling Web.DOM.Internal.Types
```

There will be various warnings emitted. But they are only *warnings*. The fact that the exact warning isn't shown by `npm` isn't great though.

You won't be able to avoid warnings, unless the developers adhere to an overly strict warning-free code (e.g. `-Werror`). Then again lot of software emits warnings during compilation, sometimes they are just compiler diagnostics.